# Notepad++: Stop convert my tab to spaces for python

Tags: notepad++

[image]

When I hit tab key in a .py file, the tab automatically converts to four spaces. I checked my settings, it should not do so. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I found in tab setting, the specific language setting was wrong.